# How to prevent one event method from completing when another event is fired in C#?

Tags: c#, events

I am looking at some framework code trying to resolve an issue.

In this framework, there are two methods that are event driven and beyond our control.

We want to prevent (as much as possible) the "AnalyzeMarket()" method from executing whenever a closing event is fired.

The AnalyzeMarket() method is called from the OnTick() method, which happens every time a new price comes in. This is
beyond our control. Also beyond our control is the Positions_Closed() method because we never know when a position will 
be close and cannot stop a position from being closed.

The basic code snippet we have is below, but doesn't work 100% of the time. We understand this because we obviously won't know
what will get the CPU's focus.

Example:

- The closing event is fired, method signature started

  - A tick comes in. CPU calls AnalyzeMarket.
  - CPU keeps executing AnalyzeMarket method beyond the "if" statement
  - CPU switches back and now sets the _wasClosingEventFired = true
  - Unfortunately, AnalyzeMarket keeps running because the flag was false when it started.

**Is there a better to do what we're trying to achieve?**

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
//Called by the framework whenever someone closes a price position
private void Positions_Closed(PositionClosedEventArgs args)
        {
        //Flag so we don't place any more orders or anything until this method completes
        _wasClosingEventFired = true;

        //other stuff this method does

        //Signal that this method is over with
        _wasClosingEventFired = false;
        }

//This method is called by the framework every time a new price comes in
//This is unpredictable and could be 1ms from "now", 2 seconds from "now", etc.
protected override void OnTick()
        {
            AnalyzeMarket();
        }

private void AnalyzeMarket()
    {
        //Does a few preliminary logging and other set ups

        if (!_wasClosingEventFired)
            {
            //Does the brunt of the work
            //This is the code we want to make sure doesn't
            //run when a closing event happens. If that means
            //we have to wait a few "ticks", that's fine.
        }

        //Clean up stuff
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Read about semaphores, http://dotnetpattern.com/threading-semaphore

Comment: Is this the same class - same method - same global namespace? "CPU calls'" is a bit vague.. what is the CPU ?

Comment: @riffnl - yes same class; yes same global namespace. the CPU - central processing unit. Main chip that runs a computer. :-) To elaborate, what I mean is the underlying part of the system that actually executes the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming these events are coming in from different threads, which is causing race-conditions for you.  This simplest way, in my opinion, to handle this race condition is using `Monitors`, in the form of `lock` statements:

```
private object sync= new object();
//Called by the framework whenever someone closes a price position
private void Positions_Closed(PositionClosedEventArgs args)
{
   lock (sync) {                 
      //other stuff this method does

   }
}

//This method is called by the framework every time a new price comes in
//This is unpredictable and could be 1ms from "now", 2 seconds from "now", etc.
protected override void OnTick()
{
   AnalyzeMarket();
}

private void AnalyzeMarket()
{
   //Does a few preliminary logging and other set ups
   lock (sync) {               
      //Does the brunt of the work
      //This is the code we want to make sure doesn't
      //run when a closing event happens. If that means
      //we have to wait a few "ticks", that's fine.

      //Clean up stuff
   }
}
```

This works by only allowing one thread at a time to enter the monitor (`lock(sync) {' enters the monitor and leaves it at the corresponding`}`.  If one thread has the lock, the other thread will block when it tries to obtain the lock until it obtains it.

Note, though, that if these happen on the same thread, you will need to add the check for `_wasClosingEventFired` just like you had originally, but inside the lock statements.

Also not, if you are doing async...await patterns within the these callbacks, you cannot `use lock() { }` to surround asynchronous codes.  In this case, use a `SemaphoreSlim` as an asynchronous-friendly mutex.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I'm familiar with lock statements and your answer seems quite simple - I hate it when overthinking things! :-) But on a serious note, is there a way to implement that when a closing-event happens, we can have it exit the AnalyzeMarket() method immediately and return? Or is that what you meant by leaving in the _wasClosingEventFired flag at all the critical junctions? (seems like that would be the easiest)

Comment: If you want the `AnalyzeMarket()` method to immediately terminate, you would have to make the code in that method listen for a cancellation flag and terminate.  The details of that would very much depend on the nature of the code in `AnalyzeMarket()`.  The only way to imperatively terminate code is to `Thread.Abort()` the entire thread-- but you probably want to avoid that if you don't fully control the entire lifecycle of the thread you are aborting.

Comment: Thanks @Tim. Yes, you're right I want to avoid that. I've instead gone with your previous suggestion of implementing the lock{} while still keeping the _wasClosingEventFired checks inside the lock statement.